# File Anti-virus and Proactive Defense failing to start in Kaspersky

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, sp3, kaspersky

Since I tried using my laptop on Saturday, my Kaspersky installation (6.0.2.678) is failing to start the file anti-virus and proactive defense protection.

I installed some drivers and CANking from KVaser on Friday, but I can't see how this would break Kaspersky. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always rollback your last update and see if that helps... After that manually initiate the update process.

Comment: The second part of this solved the issue, so I'm giving you the answer. The actual cause was that the update had been stalled (see my answer http://superuser.com/questions/137257/file-anti-virus-and-proactive-defense-failing-to-start-in-kaspersky/137466#137466)

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that Kaspersky may have been caught in the middle of an update that is yet to complete. I can't verify this until Friday - I'll update this answer once I know more.